# I'm trying to create my own strcat() function instead of implementing the one using the <cstring> library

Tags: c++, strcat

//this is my own function, when i call it nothing shows up on the screen

```
char * strcat1(char * destination, const char * value)
{
while(*destination != '\0')
    destination++;
while(*value != '\0')
{
    *destination = *value;
    destination++;
    value++;
}
*destination = '\0';

return destination;
}
```

Comment: Why should something show up on the screen? There are no output statements or anything. Anyway, I'm not ruling out the function being wrong, but [it worked when I tried](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8cb58bface026dd3). At least have an example that fails instead of leaving people to guess at how you call it.

Comment: The old-style C string functions are not a good thing to copy. They really need to know the sizes of the destination and value buffers in order to be secure and not read or write outside of the allocated array boundaries. C++ std::string and std::vector<char> are much better choices.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the function returns pointer to the terminating zero of the string pointed to by pointer destination.

The correct function can look the following way

```
char * strcat1(char * destination, const char * value)
{
    char *p = destination;

    while ( *p != '\0' ) ++p;

    while( *p++ = *value++ );

    return destination;
}
```

You can use it the following way

```
char string3[30] = "this is done";
char string4[] = " using pointers";

puts( strcat1( string3, string4 ) );
puts( string3 );
```